# jQuery Isotope error. Stopped working in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-isotope

A couple of weeks ago added some isotope to my wordpress website and got it all working well.  However, after making some changes to the site I am now getting an error message and am really struggling to figure out what is causing it as the same code works fine in JSFiddle eg. http://jsfiddle.net/ttf5776r/12/

The error message I receive in the error console when on my site is:

> TypeError: i.data(...) is undefined
>   ...)n[t]=s||"original-order"!==t?rt:i.data(this,"isotope-sort-data")[t];i.da...

I have figured out that if I remove the following code, the error message stops appearing and the isotope works but doesn't put the selected box into the top left corner due to the code that has been removed.

```
  $container
  .isotope( 'updateSortData', $this.parent() )  //this should be above the 'return false;' to make the selected photo go to top left corner but it decided to break and havem't had time to find fix. - LOL 08-01-2015
  .isotope( 'updateSortData', $previousSelected )
  .isotope();
```

Unfortunately I do not remember all of the changes I have made since this worked but I am pretty sure no JQuery amendments have been made.

Can anyone help me troubleshoot?

Code below:

functions.php

```
function add_isotope() {
    wp_register_script('isotope', 'http://isotope.metafizzy.co/v1/jquery.isotope.min.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('isotope');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_isotope' ); 

function add_jsscripts() {
    wp_register_script('jsscripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('jsscripts');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_jsscripts' );
```

Comment: This is not enough info. How are you loading your scripts? What did you change? Post additional code.

Comment: I have added code to show how I am loading the scripts.  I do not know exactly what changes I made.  Just small amendments here and there.  I have not added anything major and not changed the JQuery for this script.

Comment: Have you added jQuery in your page?

Comment: I don't see jquery loaded. If it is in "scripts", it needs to load before isotope v1.

Comment: Not enough info. Is there a link for the website?

Comment: Try adding `wp_enqueue_script('jquery')` before the isotope enque.

Comment: Yes, sharing the site will help. What about the order of the scripts? Shouldn't be jsscripts also included after isotope? I would change the array in register to array('jquery','isotope')

Comment: Yeah it could be an HTML change that messed up isotope. A link to the site would help to verify. On a side note, Git is a game changer in terms of tracking changes. If you're not comfy with command line there is alway the [gui](https://windows.github.com/) and you can use it locally, no Github required.

Answer (score 0):

Your error refers to a minified source. The first step would be to switch to using a *non-minified* source so that the variables have their original names.

At that point you find the error here ("key" becomes "t", etc.):

```
updateSortData : function( $atoms, isIncrementingElemCount ) {
  var instance = this,
      getSortData = this.options.getSortData,
      $this, sortData;
  $atoms.each(function(){
    $this = $(this);
    sortData = {};
    // get value for sort data based on fn( $elem ) passed in
    for ( var key in getSortData ) {
      if ( !isIncrementingElemCount && key === 'original-order' ) {
        // keep original order original
        sortData[ key ] = $.data( this, 'isotope-sort-data' )[ key ];
      } else {
        sortData[ key ] = getSortData[ key ]( $this, instance );
      }
    }
    // apply sort data to element
    $.data( this, 'isotope-sort-data', sortData );
  });
},
```

The error you get, "i.data() is undefined", thus becomes "$.data() is undefined" -- which seems to indicate that the `.data()` plugin is not properly loaded, or (much more likely) that the variable passed to isotope *is not actually a handle to the jQuery library*. Check how you load and initialize isotope.